# Making an ajax-based template?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, ajax, navigation

Is there any proper way to make an AJAX engine for a theme in the Joomla?

I want all of my navigation happen without the page refresh, or in other words, thorough AJAX calls. Should I rely on `com_ajax` of Joomla and write my own handlers, or there are better solutions out there?

Comment: Is one of the answers below "Acceptable" for you?  If so, please award the big green tick; otherwise, please progress your question toward resolution by clarifying (via Question Edit) what issue you are still having.

Answer (score 6):

My advice to you - avoid this. It's a recipe for many problems. A website owner who wanted this ended up paying us a lot of money just to fix the problems that arose from using this strategy (there were many, many issues). At the end, the website owner reverted back to a "non-ajax" template and never looked back again.

Issues included: Many JavaScript conflicts that were very hard to solve, near impossible to solve caching issue, indexing issues, etc...

There is not one single advantage in doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a better solution... [AddFullAjax](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/add-fullajax) is nice plugin which connects FullAjax library to Joomla site, and it may work pretty well for simple sites. Demo at http://getsite.org.ua/jdemo/ shows default Joomla 3 under AJAX technology.

But... as @itoctopus just mentioned, its far from being easy to implement, and it may simply lead to great hair loss :-(

You have been warned... ;-)